# What does "butch the clearance" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "butch the clearance" mean in football (soccer) context?

GOOOOOOOAAAAAAAL! Kane! Spurs 2 Zagreb 0
Aurier crosses into the box, Theophile-Catherine **butches the clearance**, essentially laying it off to Kane who puts the ball in the back of the net. Too easy.

Comment: could it have been "butchers the clearance"   If so you can probably check in the dictionary for the meaning "ruin" or "make a mess of"   Anyway, did you see the clearance kick?  Was it a "good" clearance or not?  I'd guess it was pretty awful

Comment: Also, please provide a source (and ideally a link) for this quote.

Comment: @JamesK I'd guess it was probably **botches**, but _butchers_ is also possible.

Comment: @TypeIA Yes, I think you're right. So with that this is easily answered by a dictionary https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/botch